# How can one use Binder (mybinder.org) with private Github repositories?

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, android-binder, reproducible-research

After reviewing this exact issue (https://github.com/jupyterhub/binderhub/issues/237) it seems that the functionality for this has been implemented with this merged pull request (https://github.com/jupyterhub/binderhub/pull/671).

However I can not seem to find guidance in the docs or elsewhere which explains what should go into the `secrets.yml` file or if there are other steps required in order to use Binder with private Github repos (Apologies if I have missed the obvious -- complete Binder noobie here)

Link to my same question in the original issue: https://github.com/jupyterhub/binderhub/issues/237#issuecomment-462711995

Comment: As an aside, https://github.com/QuantStack/voila and AWS fit my needs as opposed to the binder and private repo path.

Answer (score 4):

The 'Binder (mybinder.org)' part of the OP's question actually refers to two things.
MyBinder.org is a public BinderHub. The [issue](https://github.com/jupyterhub/binderhub/issues/237) referenced is referring to Binderhubs in general, i.e., the 'Binder' part of the OP's question. They have set it up and documented how to enable working with private Github repositories on privately-hosted Binderhubs **not via MyBinder.org**. See the changes referenced by 'docs for private repo access' [here](https://github.com/jupyterhub/binderhub/pull/783).
The discussion in the [issue](https://github.com/jupyterhub/binderhub/issues/237) referenced says they won't be allowing that for MyBinder.org.

For access to private repos, you can deploy [BinderHub](https://binderhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), the software that powers mybinder.org, yourself, or use [repo2docker](https://repo2docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), the tool that turns a repository into a Docker image that will run on  Jupyter if you only want to use it locally instead of running a service.