# Accessing spreadsheet file from google drive through notebook run in the cloud

Tags: python, github, google-drive-api, cloud, credentials

I am working on a spare-time project together with some friends. What I would like to do is to have an spreadsheet saved on Google Drive (or similar services) that me and my friends will update regularly. The data from the spreadsheet we want to visualize using Python and Jupyter Notebooks. My friends are not into programming at all, so I want them to be able to access and run the notebooks in the cloud, e.g. through mybinder.org.

I did the credentials stuff from Google API, and it works fine when I run locally. The problem, however, is that since my understanding is that I should not upload credentials to GitHub, mybinder.org is not able to get the credentials that it needs to read the spreadsheet from Google Drive. So my question is how I can solve this?

One idea is to create a separate Google Account just for putting the spreadsheet there. If I do that then maybe uploading the credentials to GitHub is fine? The data from the spreadsheet is not sensitive at all.

Comment: Does the same apply for private github repo's, i know that github offers that as a service, but i'm unsure if it's still considered not a good idea to upload to private repos

Comment: @oppresionslayer. Private repos don't work with mybinder.org. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58206433/8508004).

Answer (score 1):

You could set the file to be shared with those that have the link by selecting `Get shareable link` under 'Sharing' and then use the method described [here](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/f0f2d122e05bf5f971611258c22c110f) to bring the file into an active Jupyter session. (More on the use of `curl` to do that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48133859/8508004).)
To have it be otained as CSV you can change the end of the URL of the shareable link from `edit?usp=sharing` to `export?exportFormat=csv`, based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393858/8508004).
To execute `curl` in a Jupyter notebooks cell, you'd want to preface the command with an exclamation point so that the task is run in a shell.
Then direct the stdout to a file.
So combining that, the general form of the code cell would be:

```py
!curl https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<specific_GUID_key>/export?exportFormat=csv > output.csv
```

Instead of running the code to retrieve it from a notebook cell, the command without the exclamation point could be placed in a `start` file so the current data is retrieved each time the session is spun up. See [here](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_files.html#start-run-code-before-the-user-sessions-starts) for more about the `start` configuration file for use with Binderhubs/MyBinder.org.

You may also be interested in using [Voila](https://github.com/voila-dashboards/voila) to have them see the visualizations via a dashboard backed by the Jupyter notebook. It is able to be spawned by sessions backed by MyBinder.org, too.